# Json to Avro conversion in a json file with varying fields

Tags: json, avro, parquet

I have a problem before me to convert a `JSON` file to `avro format`. But in this case the `JSON` data has varying field values such as:

```
  {"a":"x1", "b":"x2": "c":"x3"}

  {"b":"x4", "d":"x5"}
```

I have a working code to convert the files in which the fields in each entry remains same. But `avro` being a schema definition language is not able to support the above data (with varying fields).

I have a basic question if it is even possible to use a schema and convert it to avro format for such a case? Or is there any other tool which can be used to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a schema that is the superset of all possible fields and just leave null the ones you don't have (I think that was the approach you were implying in your question.  Nulls are defined by unions in Avro, so it'd look something like this

```js
{
   "type":"record",
   "namespace":"com.mycompany",
   "name":"MYRECORD",
   "fields":[
       {
           "name":"a",
           "type":["string", "null"]
       },
       {
           "name":"b",
           "type":["string", "null"]
       },
       {
           "name":"c",
           "type":["string", "null"]
       }
   ]
}
```

If it's impossible to know all the fields up-front, another way would be to have a schema that is like

```js
{
   "type":"record",
   "namespace":"com.mycompany",
   "name":"MYRECORD",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"TheFields",
         "type":"map",
         "values":"string"
      }
   ]
}
```

But this would only work if all your fields are of the same type, and you'd have to write your own code to parse the JSON and shove it into the map.

Those are the only options I can think of.  There is no equivalent of an XML schema `<xs:any>` in Avro.  The strict schema conformity is inherent to the design.